# supervisord refused connection. Laravel

Tags: php, linux, laravel, supervisord

I am a first time supervisord user and I'm trying to get it setup and configured.

I ran `supervisord -c my/conf/file`

When running `supervisorctl -c my/conf/file` I get

`http://localhost:9001 refused connection`

My conf file is as follows:

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/etc/supervisor/supervisord.log    ; supervisord log file
logfile_maxbytes=50MB                           ; maximum size of logfile before rotation
logfile_backups=10                              ; number of backed up logfiles
loglevel=error                                  ; info, debug, warn, trace
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid                ; pidfile location
nodaemon=false                                  ; run supervisord as a daemon
minfds=1024                                     ; number of startup file descriptors
minprocs=200                                    ; number of process descriptors
user=root                                       ; default user
childlogdir=/etc/supervisor/               ; where child log files will live

[supervisorctl]
```

No much of a linux buff myself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try `ps aux | grep supervisor` to see if it is running (ignore the line that finds your search command, of course). What distro of Linux are you on? If you are on Ubuntu and Supervisord runs as a service (I don't know if it does), try `service --status-all` to see if it is running.

Comment: Anything in your logs?